# How to use PredictorMeasurements without a PredictorFunction?

Tags: machine-learning

I have the output and target values computed already from a model applied a test set, but it's not a `PredictorFunction`. Is there any way to force feed these to `PredictorMeasurements` to get the nice analytics that it provides?

```
predictions = {1.5 -> 2.1, 4->4.8, 6->5.4};
testset = {1.5 -> 2, 4 -> 5, 6 -> 5.5};
p = Predict[trainingset] (* I don't have a PredictorFunction *)
PredictorMeasurements[p (* so I don't have this first argument *), testset, "ResidualPlot"]
```